# How do I sum 2 variables from Select class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, sum

I've not done any javascript at all and I' trying to sum up 2 values from the select class. I can get both of them displayed, but not summed up. Could anyone explain why I'm getting the "[object HTMLParagraphElement]" as the answer? Thank you

```
function GetSelectedValue1() {
    const f = document.getElementById("value1");
    const result = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;


    const e = document.getElementById("value2");
    const result2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = result2;


    const g = +result + result2;
    document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = result3;

}
```

HTML (it's janky, was just testing):

```
 <div class="container vertical-center d-flex justify-content-center" id="stock-box">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-action">
                    <b>Order:</b>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <select class="custom-select" name="stock-box-margin40" id="value1">
                            <option selected>Choose Quantity</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                        <p id="result">United State</p>
                        <button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedValue1()">Get Selected Value</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <ul class="list-group" id="list-group-mtop">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-action">
                        <b>Order:</b>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <select class="custom-select" name="stock-box-margin40-3" id="value2">
                                <option selected>Choose Quantity</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                            </select>

                            <p id="result2">United State</p>
                            <button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedValue2();GetSelectedValue1()">Get Selected Value</button>
                            <p id="result3">United State</p>
                            <button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedValue1()">Get Selected Value</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = g;` Simple typo. You had `= result3`, which apparently referred to the element implicitly with that id.

Comment: I was going to write this . GetSet you are right.

Comment: I now get the result, but it's adding numbers next to each other, rather than together. I.e. 5+4 = 54. How do I fix that?

Comment: Add the "+" sign here (before the result2): `const g = +result + result2;`

Comment: Thanks @GetSet.  Just add + for the result2
     const g = +result + +result2;

Comment: Good tip @WaleedJubeh. I wasn't aware you could parseInt like that so succinctly.

Comment: Thank you all. You've got it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` because you were console logging the HTML element itself, which in here was `result3`. What you actually should have been logged was `g`. Since that's where you stored your string addition.

It's nothing but a careless mistake.

replace `result3` with `g`,

```js
// If you want to perform string addition
const g = result + result2; 

// If you want to perform numerical addition

// Using bitwise or (|) is the fastest way to convert string to number in JS
// You can also save a few bytes in your JavaScript code by using 
// the | (bitwise-or) operator instead of parseInt or 
// uniary opertor (+) as addressed in the comment section
const g = (result | 0) + (result2 | 0);

document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = g; // not result3
```

Comment: Hijacking the comment section @Vijay?

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice it earlier 

Comment: Well i guess it doesn't matter. But also OP had another problem where he/she wanted to math-wise add the values. Which was also solved in comments.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking Vijay that you might want to keep the points so deleting was not going to happen by you. But I'm learning stuff from your modified approach with the bitwise operator to parseInt. That's pretty new to me. And pretty cool. ... I was only earlier pointing out that OP must have accepted your answer without really reading it. Because earlier you didn't have the math-wise add, which was the problem OP really wanted to solve. OP had an XY problem. The string concat part was a fallacy in design.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, thus making SO better for everyone. I highly appreciate it.